# No internet connection in cmd and msys2 when using USB Tethering and Wifi Hotspot on PdaNet+

Tags: networking, dns, internet-connection, network-adapter, icmp

I used my phone to connect laptop to the internet using [PdaNet+](http://pdanet.co/).

There are two options in PdaNet+ which are USB Tether and WiFi Direct Hotspot.

I faced this problem for both the options.

I can connect to google.com using Chrome. However, when I tried to ping [google.com](https://google.com) in cmd, it showed `request time out`.

I also able download Windows update, install Python package using pip in cmd, browse Microsoft Store, etc

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [216.58.196.14] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 216.58.196.14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Below is the screenshot of my Wifi connection, it showed `No Internet`,

but in Network Status there, it shows `You're connected to the Internet`:

[image]

Below are the things I tried:

1. Run Windows Network Diagnostics, showed:

   `Your broadband modem is experiencing connectivity issues`

   Then I shut down and start my phone again, run the troubleshooter again it showed:

   `Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding`

   And I did all the methods [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/2779064/your-computer-appears-to-be-correctly-configured-but-the-device-or-res) but still no luck.
2. Run commands:

   `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` from the answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/no-internet-access-but-internet-is-working/41967ae9-3528-4518-b28e-ab3740a80e15?page=1)

   `netsh winsock reset` from the answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/your-computer-appears-to-be-correctly-configured/cc0861d8-024d-4895-bf0c-6b53f252adfb?auth=1)

The reason I want to solve this problem is that I think this is the reason I cannot install Git package in [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) based on this [issue](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/849).

I can access to `http://repo.msys2.org/` using Chrome but I don't know why it `Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org` in msys2.

The weird thing is I still can install Python package using pip in cmd.

Is this the limitation of PdaNet+? Any help is appreciated.

```
$ pacman -S msys/git
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (35) db-5.3.28-2  expat-2.2.5-1  gdbm-1.11-3  heimdal-1.5.3-9
              libgdbm-1.11-3  openssh-7.6p1-2  perl-5.24.4-1
              perl-Authen-SASL-2.16-2  perl-Convert-BinHex-1.125-1
              perl-Encode-Locale-1.05-1  perl-Error-0.17025-1
              perl-File-Listing-6.04-2  perl-HTML-Parser-3.72-2
              perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-2  perl-HTTP-Cookies-6.04-1
              perl-HTTP-Daemon-6.01-2  perl-HTTP-Date-6.02-2
              perl-HTTP-Message-6.14-1  perl-HTTP-Negotiate-6.01-2
              perl-IO-Socket-SSL-2.054-1  perl-IO-stringy-2.111-1
              perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.02-2  perl-MIME-tools-5.509-1
              perl-MailTools-2.20-1  perl-Net-HTTP-6.17-1
              perl-Net-SMTP-SSL-1.04-1  perl-Net-SSLeay-1.84-1
              perl-TermReadKey-2.37-2  perl-TimeDate-2.30-2
              perl-Try-Tiny-0.30-1  perl-URI-1.73-1  perl-WWW-RobotRules-6.02-2
              perl-libwww-6.31-2  vim-8.1.0022-1  git-2.17.1-1

Total Download Size:    27.03 MiB
Total Installed Size:  126.44 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'expat-2.2.5-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'expat-2.2.5-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'expat-2.2.5-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'vim-8.1.0022-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'vim-8.1.0022-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'vim-8.1.0022-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'heimdal-1.5.3-9-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'heimdal-1.5.3-9-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'heimdal-1.5.3-9-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'openssh-7.6p1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'openssh-7.6p1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'openssh-7.6p1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'db-5.3.28-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'db-5.3.28-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'db-5.3.28-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'libgdbm-1.11-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'libgdbm-1.11-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'libgdbm-1.11-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'gdbm-1.11-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'gdbm-1.11-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'gdbm-1.11-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-5.24.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-5.24.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-5.24.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Error-0.17025-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Error-0.17025-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Error-0.17025-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Authen-SASL-2.16-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Authen-SASL-2.16-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Authen-SASL-2.16-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Encode-Locale-1.05-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Encode-Locale-1.05-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Encode-Locale-1.05-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Date-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Date-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Date-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-File-Listing-6.04-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-File-Listing-6.04-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-File-Listing-6.04-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTML-Parser-3.72-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTML-Parser-3.72-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTML-Parser-3.72-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-URI-1.73-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-URI-1.73-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-URI-1.73-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Message-6.14-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Message-6.14-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Message-6.14-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Cookies-6.04-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Cookies-6.04-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Cookies-6.04-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Daemon-6.01-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Daemon-6.01-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Daemon-6.01-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Negotiate-6.01-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Negotiate-6.01-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-HTTP-Negotiate-6.01-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-HTTP-6.17-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-HTTP-6.17-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-HTTP-6.17-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-WWW-RobotRules-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-WWW-RobotRules-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-WWW-RobotRules-6.02-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Try-Tiny-0.30-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Try-Tiny-0.30-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Try-Tiny-0.30-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-libwww-6.31-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-libwww-6.31-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-libwww-6.31-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-TimeDate-2.30-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-TimeDate-2.30-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-TimeDate-2.30-2-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-MailTools-2.20-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-MailTools-2.20-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-MailTools-2.20-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-IO-stringy-2.111-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-IO-stringy-2.111-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-IO-stringy-2.111-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Convert-BinHex-1.125-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Convert-BinHex-1.125-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Convert-BinHex-1.125-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-MIME-tools-5.509-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-MIME-tools-5.509-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-MIME-tools-5.509-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-SSLeay-1.84-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-SSLeay-1.84-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-SSLeay-1.84-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-IO-Socket-SSL-2.054-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-IO-Socket-SSL-2.054-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-IO-Socket-SSL-2.054-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-SMTP-SSL-1.04-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-SMTP-SSL-1.04-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-Net-SMTP-SSL-1.04-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-TermReadKey-2.37-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-TermReadKey-2.37-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'perl-TermReadKey-2.37-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'git-2.17.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : Could not resolve host: repo.msys2.org
error: failed retrieving file 'git-2.17.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from downloads.sourceforge.net : Could not resolve host: downloads.sourceforge.net
error: failed retrieving file 'git-2.17.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : Could not resolve host: www2.futureware.at
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```